# How to set up strongly typed configuration in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

[This article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/284/asp-net-5-configuration) and [this other article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jun/03/Strongly-typed-AppSettings-Configuration-in-ASPNET-5) show how you can map your appsettings to a class in ASP.NET 5.

From the first link:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetConfigurationSection("AppSettings"));
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

However, I'm not getting the `Configure()` method on `services`. So either I'm missing a package, or the API has changed. Which is it?

I'm using RC1. I believe the articles are based on beta 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should give you what you need. I have this class:

```
public class UIOptions
{
    public UIOptions()
    { }

    public int DefaultPageSize_SiteList { get; set; } = 10;
    public int DefaultPageSize_CountryList { get; set; } = 10;
    public int DefaultPageSize_StateList { get; set; } = 10;
    public int DefaultPageSize_RoleList { get; set; } = 10;
    public int DefaultPageSize_RoleMemberList { get; set; } = 10;
    public int DefaultPageSize_UserList { get; set; } = 10;
    public int DefaultPageSize_LogView { get; set; } = 10;

}
```

If I want to override any of the default values I can add this in my appsettings.json:

```
"UIOptions": {
"DefaultPageSize_SiteList" : "5"
}
```

But if I'm not changing anything it doesn't matter if this exists in the appsettings.json file.

In startup I have this:

```
services.Configure<UIOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("UIOptions"));
```

In a controller where I need the options injected I have a constructor dependency on

```
IOptions<UIOptions>
```

Note that I get my UIOptions instance from the .Value property of the IOptions

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

public class CoreDataController : Controller
{
    public CoreDataController(
        IOptions<UIOptions> uiOptionsAccessor
        )
    {

        uiOptions = uiOptionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    private UIOptions uiOptions;

}
```

Comment: Very nice example, but I don't have the services.Configure(). So the most important thing for me is to know the NuGet dependencies required for that to work.

Comment: namespace where that extension lives is Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package where it lives is "Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel` did it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package. The package names were changes somewhere around beta8

Comment: It's actually `Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel`.