# How to set up and work with ASP.net 5 RC1 Configurations?

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core

I am very confused with how the new configuration system works in the ASP.net 5. Yes, I know I create a config.json, but how do I access its contents in my code, especially in Startup.cs?

Many tutorials use the `Configuration` class that doesn't seem to exist with `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`. They seem to use `Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel`. Isn't that "no longer in effect"? I assume that because Intellisense doesn't give me a 1.0.0-rc1-* for it.

I cannot find an updated guide on how to work with Configurations in ASP.net 5 RC1. Someone please tell me how to do this.

Also, I need some help with environment variables and how they interact with the new Configuration framework, if they're meant to interact in some way. I want to be able to run the application with the option of running it as dev and deploying it as release.

Comment: `Microsoft.Framework.*` has been renamed to `Microsoft.Extensions.*`. [See this announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/77). Also, I highly recommend it to subscribe to notifications on that repo.

Answer (score 0):

In Startup.cs you can setup multiple configuration sources, you can use a json file like appsettings.json, you can use environment variables, and you can also use a new thing called usersecrets. The order in which you add them is important since each config source could duplicate the same settings.
The later you add the config source the more priority it gets. Consider this sample from my own project and also see the comments:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
{
    // This reads the configuration keys from the secret store.
    // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
builder.AddUserSecrets();
}

// this file name is ignored by gitignore in my project
// so you can create it and use on your local dev machine
// remember last config source added wins if it has the same settings
builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.overrides.json", optional: true);

 // most common use of environment variables would be in azure hosting
// since it is added last anything in env vars would trump the same setting in previous config sources
 // so no risk of messing up settings if deploying a new version to azure
builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
Configuration = builder.Build();
```

Then as far as storing configuration settings you should use classes with properties that can be mapped from configuration at startup and registered with the DI services so they can be injected wherever you need them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515670/how-to-set-up-strongly-typed-configuration-in-asp-net-5/34515858#34515858) for a detailed example.

Update: the following packages come from my project.json and are the needed/related packages, intellisense or not these are currently valid:

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
```

Comment: [my answer on this question shows how to set usersecrets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599573/how-do-i-inject-asp-net-5-vnext-user-secrets-into-my-own-utility-class/32608820#32608820) which is very similar to how you set environment variables. It should also be helpful for you.